# Tensorflow Bazel 0.3.0 build CUDA 8.0 GTX 1070 fails

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, cudnn

Here are my specs:

- GTX 1070
- Driver 367 (installed from .run)
- Ubuntu 16.04
- CUDA 8.0 (installed from .run)
- Cudnn 5
- Bazel 0.3.0 (potential problem?)
- gcc 4.9.3
- Tensorflow installed from source

To verify versions:

```
volcart@volcart-Precision-Tower-7910:~/$ nvidia-smi
Fri Aug  5 15:03:32 2016       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.35                 Driver Version: 367.35                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1070    Off  | 0000:03:00.0      On |                  N/A |
|  0%   38C    P8    11W / 185W |    495MiB /  8113MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     20303    G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             280MiB |
|    0     20909    G   compiz                                         114MiB |
|    0     21562    G   ...s-passed-by-fd --v8-snapshot-passed-by-fd    98MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
volcart@volcart-Precision-Tower-7910:~/$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_May__4_21:01:56_CDT_2016
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.26
volcart@volcart-Precision-Tower-7910:~/$ bazel version
Build label: 0.3.0
Build target: bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Fri Jun 10 11:38:23 2016 (1465558703)
Build timestamp: 1465558703
Build timestamp as int: 1465558703
volcart@volcart-Precision-Tower-7910:~/$ gcc -vUsing built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.9.3-13ubuntu2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.3 (Ubuntu 4.9.3-13ubuntu2)
```

I did switch bazel versions, so I executed `bazel clean` successfully.

I can verify CUDA is functional via `~/NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery$`

```
volcart@volcart-Precision-Tower-7910:~/NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery$ ./deviceQuery 
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 1070"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          8.0 / 8.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    6.1
  Total amount of global memory:                 8113 MBytes (8507162624 bytes)
  (15) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA Cores/MP:     1920 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1797 MHz (1.80 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             4004 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              256-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 2097152 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(131072), 2D=(131072, 65536), 3D=(16384, 16384, 16384)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(32768), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(32768, 32768), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 2 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 3 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 8.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 8.0, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GeForce GTX 1070
Result = PASS
```

When I `./configure` I enter all the defaults.

**The current errors**

When I build the training example I get this:

```
volcart@volcart-Precision-Tower-7910:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow$ sudo bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer
Sending SIGTERM to previous Bazel server (pid=7108)... done.
.
INFO: Found 1 target...

...

./tensorflow/core/platform/default/logging.h: In instantiation of 'std::string* tensorflow::internal::Check_LTImpl(const T1&, const T2&, const char*) [with T1 = int; T2 = long unsigned int; std::string = std::basic_string<char>]':
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:567:5:   required from here
./tensorflow/core/platform/default/logging.h:197:35: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
 TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(Check_LT, < )
                                   ^
./tensorflow/core/platform/macros.h:54:29: note: in definition of macro 'TF_PREDICT_TRUE'
 #define TF_PREDICT_TRUE(x) (x)
                             ^
./tensorflow/core/platform/default/logging.h:197:1: note: in expansion of macro 'TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL'
 TF_DEFINE_CHECK_OP_IMPL(Check_LT, < )
 ^
ERROR: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/BUILD:199:1: Linking of rule '//tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer' failed: crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc failed: error executing command third_party/gpus/crosstool/clang/bin/crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc -o bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/cc/tutorials_example_trainer ... (remaining 805 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/cc/_objs/tutorials_example_trainer/tensorflow/cc/tutorials/example_trainer.o: In function `tensorflow::example::ConcurrentSteps(tensorflow::example::Options const*, int)':
example_trainer.cc:(.text._ZN10tensorflow7example15ConcurrentStepsEPKNS0_7OptionsEi+0x517): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_'
bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/libidentity_reader_op.lo(identity_reader_op.o): In function `tensorflow::IdentityReader::SerializeStateLocked(std::string*)':
identity_reader_op.cc:(.text._ZN10tensorflow14IdentityReader20SerializeStateLockedEPSs[_ZN10tensorflow14IdentityReader20SerializeStateLockedEPSs]+0x36): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::MessageLite::SerializeToString(std::string*) const'
bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/libwhole_file_read_ops.lo(whole_file_read_ops.o): In function `tensorflow::WholeFileReader::SerializeStateLocked(std::string*)':
```

And when I try to build the `pip` package I get this:

```
volcart@volcart-Precision-Tower-7910:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow$ sudo bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
WARNING: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/util/python/BUILD:11:16: in includes attribute of cc_library rule //util/python:python_headers: 'python_include' resolves to 'util/python/python_include' not in 'third_party'. This will be an error in the future.
WARNING: /home/volcart/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/109ad80a732aaece8a87d1e3693889e7/external/gemmlowp/BUILD:102:12: in hdrs attribute of cc_library rule @gemmlowp//:eight_bit_int_gemm: Artifact 'external/gemmlowp/public/bit_depth.h' is duplicated (through '@gemmlowp//:eight_bit_int_gemm_public_headers' and '@gemmlowp//:gemmlowp_headers').
WARNING: /home/volcart/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/109ad80a732aaece8a87d1e3693889e7/external/gemmlowp/BUILD:102:12: in hdrs attribute of cc_library rule @gemmlowp//:eight_bit_int_gemm: Artifact 'external/gemmlowp/public/gemmlowp.h' is duplicated (through '@gemmlowp//:eight_bit_int_gemm_public_headers' and '@gemmlowp//:gemmlowp_headers').
WARNING: /home/volcart/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/109ad80a732aaece8a87d1e3693889e7/external/gemmlowp/BUILD:102:12: in hdrs attribute of cc_library rule @gemmlowp//:eight_bit_int_gemm: Artifact 'external/gemmlowp/public/map.h' is duplicated (through '@gemmlowp//:eight_bit_int_gemm_public_headers' and '@gemmlowp//:gemmlowp_headers').
WARNING: /home/volcart/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/109ad80a732aaece8a87d1e3693889e7/external/gemmlowp/BUILD:102:12: in hdrs attribute of cc_library rule @gemmlowp//:eight_bit_int_gemm: Artifact 'external/gemmlowp/public/output_stages.h' is duplicated (through '@gemmlowp//:eight_bit_int_gemm_public_headers' and '@gemmlowp//:gemmlowp_headers').
WARNING: /home/volcart/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/109ad80a732aaece8a87d1e3693889e7/external/gemmlowp/BUILD:102:12: in hdrs attribute of cc_library rule @gemmlowp//:eight_bit_int_gemm: Artifact 'external/gemmlowp/profiling/instrumentation.h' is duplicated (through '@gemmlowp//:eight_bit_int_gemm_public_headers' and '@gemmlowp//:gemmlowp_headers').
WARNING: /home/volcart/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/109ad80a732aaece8a87d1e3693889e7/external/gemmlowp/BUILD:102:12: in hdrs attribute of cc_library rule @gemmlowp//:eight_bit_int_gemm: Artifact 'external/gemmlowp/profiling/profiler.h' is duplicated (through '@gemmlowp//:eight_bit_int_gemm_public_headers' and '@gemmlowp//:gemmlowp_headers').
INFO: Found 1 target...
INFO: From Compiling external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/util/internal/utility.cc [for host]:


...

INFO: From Compiling tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/tensor_coding.cc:
tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/tensor_coding.cc: In member function 'bool tensorflow::TensorResponse::ParseTensorSubmessage(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*, tensorflow::TensorProto*)':
tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/tensor_coding.cc:123:23: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
         if (num_bytes != buf.size()) return false;
                       ^
ERROR: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:1498:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '//tensorflow/core/kernels:batchtospace_op_gpu':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'tensorflow/core/kernels/batchtospace_op_gpu.cu.cc':
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/cuda_runtime.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/host_config.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/builtin_types.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/device_types.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/host_defines.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/driver_types.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/surface_types.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/texture_types.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/vector_types.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/library_types.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/channel_descriptor.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/cuda_runtime_api.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/cuda_device_runtime_api.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/driver_functions.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/vector_functions.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/vector_functions.hpp'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/common_functions.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/math_functions.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/math_functions.hpp'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/math_functions_dbl_ptx3.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/math_functions_dbl_ptx3.hpp'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/cuda_surface_types.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/cuda_texture_types.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/device_functions.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/device_functions.hpp'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/device_atomic_functions.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/device_atomic_functions.hpp'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/device_double_functions.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/device_double_functions.hpp'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/sm_20_atomic_functions.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/sm_20_atomic_functions.hpp'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/sm_32_atomic_functions.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/sm_32_atomic_functions.hpp'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/sm_35_atomic_functions.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/sm_60_atomic_functions.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/sm_60_atomic_functions.hpp'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/sm_20_intrinsics.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/sm_20_intrinsics.hpp'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/sm_30_intrinsics.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/sm_30_intrinsics.hpp'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/sm_32_intrinsics.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/sm_32_intrinsics.hpp'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/sm_35_intrinsics.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/surface_functions.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/texture_fetch_functions.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/texture_indirect_functions.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/surface_indirect_functions.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/device_launch_parameters.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/cuda_fp16.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/math_constants.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/curand_kernel.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/curand.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/curand_discrete.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/curand_precalc.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/curand_mrg32k3a.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/curand_mtgp32_kernel.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/cuda.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/curand_mtgp32.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/curand_philox4x32_x.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/curand_globals.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/curand_uniform.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/curand_normal.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/curand_normal_static.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/curand_lognormal.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/curand_poisson.h'
  '/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/curand_discrete2.h'.
nvcc warning : option '--relaxed-constexpr' has been deprecated and replaced by option '--expt-relaxed-constexpr'.
nvcc warning : option '--relaxed-constexpr' has been deprecated and replaced by option '--expt-relaxed-constexpr'.
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 138.913s, Critical Path: 102.63s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw some people complaining about bazel 0.3.1, maybe need to downgrade to 0.3.0. The error you gave is not very informative, that's just the parent script saying that child script failed, there should be more info on the console with the actual error.

I went through the setup steps two days ago for GTX 1080 and it worked with this config.

```
Ubuntu 16.04
Nvidia Driver: nvidia-367.35 (installed from .run file)
Bazel 0.3.0
gcc: 4.9.3 (default with 16.04)
CUDA 8.0.27 (installed from .run file into default dirs)
compute capability: (use default values for config)
```

Comment: I tried your configuration and installed from run files, but the problem persists. I added the entire error log.

Comment: Looks like it can't find protobuf, are you following the directions for [installing from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources)? Bazel 0.3 is supposed to download protobuf sources when you first build. Also may need to do ` bazel clean` if you are switching configs around

Comment: I redid the entire post to include all steps I have taken, including yours. I have also included version verifications.

Comment: So now you don't have protobuf error anymore but have undeclared_inclusions error?

Comment: Correct, I believe `bazel clean` resolved the protobuf

Comment: The inclusions error happens if you don't update CROSSTOOL file

Comment: Ah yes lol I forget about that. Everything appears to be functional now! Thank you for all your help!