# Is it possible to build TensorFlow for GTX 1070?

Tags: ubuntu, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit with an Nvidia video card - GTX 1070 (10th generation). I'm trying to build TensorFlow.

I tried building it with CUDA 7.5 and CuDNN 5, but it turned out the CUDA 7.5 I installed requires the 352.63.0 video driver, while the video driver I downloaded from Nvidia for GTX 1070 was 367.35 - a newer version.

TensorFlow managed to build, but when I ran the example, there was a problem in runtime:

```
boyko@boyko-pc:~/Desktop/tensorflow/tensorflow/models/image/mnist$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib python3 convolutional.py
```

It failed to find CUDA because of driver mismatch:

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:491] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:296] kernel version 367.35.0 does not match DSO version 352.63.0 -- cannot find working devices in this configuration
```

Full log - http://pastebin.com/xiYtNsHk

CUDA 7.5 needs driver the 352.63 video driver, but GTX 1070 needs 367.35. The problem is TensorFlow officially supports only CUDA 7.5. So the requirements are a bit contradictory.

What do I need to do? Is it possible to use the 352.63 driver on a GTX 1070, will it run, even if it enables a limited feature-set? Or is there a CUDA 7.5 version built against this driver, or is there a way to build TensorFlow against CUDA 8.0?

This is a related question I found - [Tensorflow Bazel 0.3.0 build CUDA 8.0 GTX 1070 fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794497/tensorflow-bazel-0-3-0-build-cuda-8-0-gtx-1070-fails).

Comment: GTX 1070 is a pascal card which needs CUDA 8.0 (TF + CUDA 7.5 + Pascal will give unexpected results/NaNs).  CUDA 8 is not officially supported, but seems to work if you build from source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to build tensorflow and it seems to be working correctly.
As hinted in other answers, the lowest versions that work, *correctly*, with GTX 10xx are cuDNN 5 and CUDA 8.0, but *not the video driver that comes with CUDA 8.0.*
Here are the steps I used:

### Configuration Set-up

- Install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Install CUDA 8.0 RC ("yes" to "update" video driver - 361.77, use the .run file, into /usr/local/cuda-8.0).
- Install a video driver that supports Pascal GPUs (I used 367.35)
- Install cuDNN 5 (into /usr/local/cuda)
- Install Bazel (didn't document the details here)

### Building tensorflow

- If /usr/local/cuda is a symlink, I recomment to delete it.
- Download tensorflow sources from master branch (commit ca. 22/8/2016)
- edit tensorflow/third_party/gpus/crosstool/CROSSTOL and add:
  cxx_builtin_include_directory: "/usr/local/cuda-8.0" (**note: symlink did not work, use actual path**) [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3786)
  (Bazel fails to open the CUDA includes)
- ./configure
- bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
- cd bazel-bin
- tensorflow/tools/pip-package/build_pip_package [outfilename]
- pip or pip3 install [outfilename]

### Testing tensorflow

- export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
- [python or python3] [python-libs-path]/tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py
- Test error: 0.7%.

*If the test error is huge, it may mean that you need to upgrade cuDNN.

*Instead of building tensorflow, it's possible to install a binary release of tensorflow with cuDNN 4, CUDA 7.5, and the latest video driver. Some things like matmul will work, and others like conv2d's will not, under 10xx GPUs. Currently, binary releases of tensorflow don't support this hardware but I'm sure this will change.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to join the [NVIDIA developer program](https://developer.nvidia.com/join) in order to get CUDA 8.0 release candidate right now, because the official version is not out yet. You should be able to install this just fine on your 1070 (I have it working on a 1080). The older drivers and CUDA versions don't even support Pascal architecture, so you will have to go this route.

Then you will need to build tensorflow from [source](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources), and this time it should work.

Answer (score 2):

> What do I need to do? Is it possible to use the 352.63 driver on a GTX 1070, will it run, even if it enables a limited feature-set? Or is there a CUDA 7.5 version built against this driver, or is there a way to build TensorFlow against CUDA 8.0?

You can build it against CUDA 8.0. I have done so successfully with a GTX 1070. Specifically, I was able to build and install tensor flow from source with: NVIDIA driver 367.35, CUDA 8.0 RC, cuDNN 5.1, on Ubuntu 14.04. This will build TensorFlow with the maximum functionality using all features offered by both the Pascal GPUs and CUDA 8.0.